# Windows Phone Web browser and Javascript Compatability

Tags: javascript, windows-mobile, browser

I am pretty new to the windows phone stuff and programming for windows phone.  I made a link to navigate to a survey from surveymonkey.com which uses javascript sliders/progress. This works fine in the browser but when I loaded it up in the windows phone browser I get a nice message saying "Javascript is require for this site to function, please enable."  This was a message created by the site.

Has anyone else encountered a problem like this/found a solution?  I would assume that the phone supports some javascript ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a boolean on the windows phone WebBroswer control called "IsScriptEnabled" which allows for more javascript capabilities.